# Can someone confirm if my the minimum element in a bitonic sequence algorithm is correct or not?

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have a sequence with me which is first monotonically decreasing and then monotonically increasing of the following form , f(1) > f(2) > f(3) > f(4) ....... > f(k-1) > f(k) < f(k+1) < f(k+2) < ....... < f(n) and I want to be able to find the element k such that f(k) is the minimum in the sequence and in O(lgn) time, To solve this problem I devised the following binary search based algorithm, can someone tell me if the algorithm is correct or not -:

Properties used to decide where the binary search will recurse -:

```
FindMin(F , lo , hi)

if(lo == hi) return F[lo];

int mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2;

// recurse to the left
if(F[mid] < F[mid+1]) return FindMin(F , lo , mid);
// recurse to the right
if(F[mid] < F[mid - 1]) return FindMin(F , mid , hi);

return F[mid];
```

Can someone confirm me if my algorithm is correct or not?

Comment: Binary search on 'am I less than the value on my left'?  Or use fact that if 3 subsamples are monotonic, the lowest point is not between the highest two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current algorithm is incorrect, but you're quite close to it. Here I will show where your algorithm might go wrong.

Consider the array `[3,2,1,2]`.

Suppose first you call `FindMin(F, 0, 3)`

```
FindMin(F, 0, 3)
--mid = 1
--Check F[1] False
--Check F[1] True, call FindMin(F, 1, 3)
----mid = 2
----Check F[2] True, call FindMin(F, 1, 2)
------mid = 1
------Check F[1] False
------Check F[1] True, call FindMin(F, 1, 2)
--------mid = 1
--------Check F[1] False
--------Check F[1] True, call FindMin(F, 1, 2)
... This will continue forever until out of memory
```

You can change it a bit to get it correct:

```
FindMin(F, lo, hi){
    if(lo==hi) return F[lo];
    int mid = lo + (hi-lo)/2 // Actually you can change this into (lo+hi)/2
    if(F[mid] > F[mid+1]) return FindMin(F, mid+1, hi) // Change the comparison and recursive call!
    if(F[mid] > F[mid-1]) return FindMin(F, lo, mid-1) // Change the comparison and recursive call!
    // If we reach here, that means F[mid-1] > F[mid] < F[mid+1]
    return F[mid]
}
```

Although as @Joni said, you need to handle boundary cases. Checking only `F[mid+1]` will do the trick. I guarantee this following code won't get any out of bounds error and correct:

```
FindMin(F, lo, hi){
    if(lo==hi) return F[lo];                           // Line 1
    int mid = (lo+hi)/2                                // Line 2
    if(F[mid] > F[mid+1]) return FindMin(F, mid+1, hi) // Line 3
    else return FindMin(F, lo, mid)                    // Line 4
}
```

Call the function with `hi` as the last index in the array

Line 1 is the base case.

Line 2 computes the middle index. Note that `mid < hi` here, since `mid == hi` implies `lo == hi`, which is already covered in Line 1. So `mid` never points to the last index in the array. So it's safe to check `F[mid+1]`

Line 3 checks whether `F[mid] > F[mid+1]`, if it is, then `F[mid]` can't be the answer, since it's bigger than some number, and `F[lo..mid-1]` will also be bigger, so the answer must be in `F[mid+1..hi]`. So call `FindMin(F, mid+1, hi)`. Note that `mid+1 > lo`, and so the range `mid+1..hi` is smaller than `lo..hi`.

Line 4: If we get here, that means `F[mid] < F[mid+1]`. So the answer can be anywhere in `F[lo..mid]`. So call `FindMin(F, lo, mid)`. Note that since `mid < hi`, `FindMin(F, lo, mid)` will be different from `FindMin(F, lo, hi)`. More specifically, the range decreases, like the case in Line 3.

Combining Line 3 and Line 4, each call to `FindMin` is made with decreasing range, so the algorithm should stop after some time, which would be in the Line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `mid = k`. Then the first condition is true and you recur on `lo, mid`. Over that section the elements are in descending order, and it will follow the second condition until you are recurring on `k-1, k`. But `mid = k-1 + (k-(k-1))/2 = k-1` by integer division. This is not right. It will continue satisfying the second condition - infinite loop on `k-1, k`.

It looks like your comparison signs are backwards.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle of the algorithm is correct: use the middle point to decide if the minimum is to the right or to the left.

It is not entirely correct though. To see that think about what happens when `mid` is the minimum element: since `F[mid] < F[mid+1]` and also `F[mid] < F[mid-1]` you can never return the minimum; you enter an infinite recursion. There is an easy fix though.

Another thing that you have to keep in mind is what happens if the minimum is the first or last element in the sequence: you cannot compute `F[mid-1]` or `F[mid+1]` as the index would go out of bounds.